Incorrect/empty dag Run_ID is opening when i click on previous dag Run_id
I have an Apache Airflow server running version 1.10.10. I'm encountering an issue where, after the DAGs have completed, attempting to view the graph of a previous Run_ID does not display the correct DAG. Instead, it either shows a different DAG or an empty DAG run. How can I resolve this issue?
I have tried updating every configuration items but nothing got improved. Let me know any suggestions to resolve the issue.
